# D7 500 error after accidental deletion of base theme

Tags: theming

I am using adaptive theme as a base for my sub theme and I accidentally deleted the base theme. I knew it wasn't supposed to be a big problem if I just re-downloaded and dropped  the theme back in the file directory but upon doing so I continued to get a 500 error.

update : the specific error in the sites log, not the server log is:

```
   Call to undefined function load_subtheme_media_queries()
```

Comment: I fixed it myself somehow. Even though I had done it probably 3 times before I put a fresh download of adaptive theme in and it started working again out of nowhere. Before I put it in the very last time about the only thing I tried was  doing a                                     // Rebuild .info data.
system_rebuild_theme_data();
// Rebuild theme registry.
drupal_theme_rebuild();